# Dificulty with this Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I'm trying to prove this inequality

$|2x^2y-xz|+|x|^2\leq|2xy-z|^2+2|x|^2$, but I have had dificulties because the only hypothesis  is that $|y|\leq 1$.

Thank´s for your help.

Comment: simplify the inequality first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|2x^2y-xz| = |x||2xy-z|$. Thus you prove: $|x||2xy-z| \le |2xy-z|^2 + |x|^2$,and this is clear since $|x||2xy-z| \le 2|x||2xy-z| \le |2xy-z|^2+|x|^2$ due to $2ab \le a^2+b^2$ is true.

Comment: Thank´s so much.